# How to delete all the cache using predis in php

Tags: php, predis

I am using predis library to cache the data. I am able to delete the cache individually using

> $redis->cache->hdel(self::$cacheNamespace, $key);

But i need to delete all the cache without providing any keys, Is there a way to achieve that in predis.

Answer (score 5):

With Cache Clear All, Here you go:

```
cache_clear_all();
```

For my point of view, You have to use redis cli:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

For more info [FlushAll](http://redis.io/commands/flushall).

Comment: Yes that will work, but i need to run it programmatically using predis client.

Comment: Actually i am specifically looking for predis solution

Answer (score 4):

Try this:  `$redis->flushAll();`

Comment: `$redis->flushall()` in my version (1.1)

Answer (score 2):

**PHP Method Predis\Client::flushAll Code Examples**

predis equivalent of redis-cli FLUSHALL

```
public function flushAll()
{
    $this->_redis->flushAll();
}
```

- Removes data from ALL databases.

Answer (score 0):

There two flush functions. One of them for all Redis databases, another is only for specific Redis db. Use them like;

```
flushAll()
```

Description: **Remove all keys from all databases.**

Parameters
async (bool) requires server version 4.0.0 or greater

Return value
BOOL: Always TRUE.

Example

```
$redis->flushAll();
```

---

```
flushDb()
```

Description: **Remove all keys from the current database.**

Parameters
async (bool) requires server version 4.0.0 or greater

Return value
BOOL: Always TRUE.

Example

```
$redis->flushDb();
```

Source: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#flushdb